# queryBroadcastReceivers with PACKAGE_REPLACED

Tags: android, android-intent

The following code returns an empty list, whereas the app running it has this particular intent registered!?

```
pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(new Intent(Intent.PACKAGE_REPLACED), PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS | PackageManager.GET_DISABLED_COMPONENTS);
```

Is there a way to retrieve all receivers for such intent and other similar ones?

This method seems very unreliable or did I do something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research, only the [source code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/com/android/server/IntentResolver.java#IntentResolver.buildResolveList%28android.content.Intent,android.util.FastImmutableArraySet,boolean,boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.List,java.util.List,int%29) provided some insights on this:

When only specifying an action in the intent, the API will filter for all receivers that accepts such action without any data type or scheme.

Turns out many action intents require a scheme or data type, such as the 'package' scheme on any PACKAGE_* actions.

So the intent needs to specify the "package" scheme.

Comment: Hey, did you find any workaround for that? Maybe get all the receivers' intent filters somehow and iterate them?

Comment: I didn't find a way to get all intent filters, seem to need filtering at least on the action (?). So instead I made multiple query for the same action with the different expected types and schemes.

Answer (score 0):

can get info use code like

```
List<String> startupApps = new ArrayList<String>();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
Uri uriInfo = Uri.parse("package://");
intent.setData(uriInfo);
final List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager
                .queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : activities) {
        ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
        if (activityInfo != null)
            startupApps.add(activityInfo.name);
}
```